# How to match 2 array?

Tags: regex, perl

I have 2 files I need to match.

*File1.txt* contains:

```
-----------------------------------------------
Words | Keyword | Sentence
-----------------------------------------------
Lunch  >WORDS>    when do you want to have lunch?.
Hate   >WORDS>    I hate you.
Other  >WORDS>    Other than that?
```

*File2.txt* contains:

```
I love you.
Other than that?. 
I like you.
when do you want to have lunch?.
```

*File1* will do the word matching with *File2*, after this `keyword` `>WORDS>`. Meaning *File1* and *File2* just compare the word "Other than that?" and "when do you want to have lunch?". So the result will take the same word after the `keywords >WORDS>.` I use array to do.

The expected output will print:

```
Other  >WORDS>    Other than that?. 
Lunch  >WORDS>    when do you want to have lunch?.
```

CODE:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use Data::Dumper;
use 5.010;

my $new= File1.txt;                #read File1
my $old= File2.txt;                #read File2
my $string1;
my $string2;
my @new_array;
my @old_array;
my $string11;
my @array1;

#---------------------------------------------------------------
#   Main
#---------------------------------------------------------------

open(NEW_FILE,"<", $new) || die "Cannot open file $new to Read! - $!"; 
open(OLD_FILE,"<", $old) || die "Cannot open file $old to Read! - $!";

while (<NEW_FILE>) {
    my $string1= $_;
    my $string11= $_;
    if ($string1=~ m/WORDS/){      #matching the Keyword >WORDS>
        $string1 = $';         #string1 will take after >WORDS>
        $string11 = $_;        #string11 will take the full.
        push (@new_array, ($string1));      #string1 = @new_array
        push (@array1, ($string11));    }}  #string11 = @array1

while (<OLD_FILE>) {
    my $string2= $_;
    if ($string2 =~ m/WORDS/){  #matching the Keyword >WORDS>
        $string2 = $';          #string2 will take after >WORDS>
        push (@old_array, ($string2));   #string2 = @old_array
        }}

#------Do comparison between new file and old file. (only after WORDS)
my @intersection =();
my @unintersection = ();
my %hash1 = map{$_ => 1} @old_array;

foreach (@new_array){
    if (defined $hash1{$_}){    
        push @intersection, $_; #this one will take the same array between new and old
    }
    else { 
        push @unintersection, $_;   #this one will take the new array only. So, will read this one.
    }}
```

Until this part, if I print the `@unintersection`, it will produce:

```
other than that?
when do you want to have lunch?.
```

Do comparison between`@unintersection` (result after WORDS) and (`@array1`).

```
my @same();
my @not_same= ();
my %hash2 = map{$_ => 1} @unintersection;

foreach (@array1) {
    if (@array1 = m/WORDS/){      
        @array1 = $';
        if (defined $hash2{$_}) {
            @array1 = $_;
            push @same, $_;             
        }
        else {
            push @not_same, $_;}}}

print @same;
print @not_same;

close(NEW_FILE);
close(OLD_FILE);
close(NEW_OUTPUT_FILE);
```

The result that I produce only 1. have lunch?"

```
Other  >WORDS>    Other than that?
```

Should be got 2 output. "Other >WORDS> Other than that?" and "Lunch >WORDS> when do you want to have lunch?"

Comment: mind trailing empty spaces or use `chomp`. Also you might want to use hashes and just look for matching keys. Also a simple shell solution: `cat f2.txt | while read line; do grep "$line" f1.txt ; done` if I correctly understood the question

Comment: you are doing it overly complicated. you need to use hashes. Loop over file2 and add it to your lookup hash. then loop over file1 and see where the hash contains those words. its really simple and superfast with a hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved with a lookup table (implemented as hashref) build on information provided in **File1.txt** (`words_lookup.dat`).

Once we have lookup table at our disposal read **File2.txt** (`words_data.dat`) and compare with lookup table. If the input line matches lookup table then output stored value (`$lookup->{$1}{line}`) to the console.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my($fh, $lookup);

my $fname_lookup = 'words_lookup.dat';    # File1.txt
my $fname_data   = 'words_data.dat';      # File2.txt
my $re_lookup    = qr/(\S+)\s+>WORDS>\s+(.*)/;

open $fh, '<', $fname_lookup
    or die "Couldn't open $fname_lookup";
    
while( <$fh> ) {
    chomp;
    next unless /$re_lookup/;
    $lookup->{$1}{sentence} = $2;
    $lookup->{$1}{line} = $_;
}

close $fh;

open $fh, '<', $fname_data
    or die "Couldn't open $fname_data";
    
while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    $line =~ /$lookup->{$_}{sentence}/ && say $lookup->{$_}{line} for keys $lookup->%*;
}

close $fh;

exit 0;
```

Output

```
Other  >WORDS>    Other than that?
Lunch  >WORDS>    when do you want to have lunch?.
```

Comment: Think you need to explain what `%*` does

Comment: It indicates that variable holds a _hash reference_ - documentation [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref), look for `$href->%*;  # same as  %{ $href }`. This operation dereferences a hash referenced by __href__ variable.